# what is the Non-cyclical definition of NP-hard?

Tags: computer-science, theory, computation-theory

I am trying to comprehend the concepts [NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29), [NP complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and [NP hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) according to Wikipedia.

If I inderstand the given text correctly:

EDIT: corrected according to David

**NP** == decision problem whose answer can be verified in polynomial time (given the solution)

**NP complete** == **NP** and **NP hard** simultaneously

**NP hard** == there is a **NP complete** problem which is polynomial time Turing reducible to it.

So in order to understand the concept of **NP completeness**, I need to understand the **NP hardness** first. So I try to analyze what is **NP hard** according to the above statements. So I get:

**NP hard** == there is a problem which is **NP hard**  and **NP** simultaneously, which is reducible to it. But there is a cycle in the definition. What is the noncyclical definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete#Formal_definition_of_NP-completeness

Comment: Well, I guess it is time to get some sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define NP-complete as a problem such that any NP-problem can be reduced to it in polynomial time. That definition should remove your cycle.

Your definition of NP-hard seems backwards. It should be that a problem is NP hard if some NP-complete problem (thus any NP problem) can be reduced to it in polynomial time.

You can see more detail here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem